# Windows OpenNMS - PostgreSQL/Java database issue

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, opennms

**OpenNMS - PostgreSQL/Java database issue**

I understand that the jicmp files aren't causing fatal errors, but when OpenNMS goes to create a user, there seems to be a Java exception.

Does anybody with experience know what's causing this at all?

Errors dumped from the OpenNMS installer

```
- using SQL directory... C:\Program Files\OpenNMS\etc
- using create.sql... C:\Program Files\OpenNMS\etc\create.sql
* using 'postgres' as the PostgreSQL user for OpenNMS
* using 'opennms' as the PostgreSQL database name for OpenNMS
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.opennms.bootstrap.Bootstrap$4.run(Bootstrap.java:460)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opennms.core.schema.MigrationException: an error occurred creating the OpenNMS user
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.createUser(Migrator.java:339)
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.prepareDatabase(Migrator.java:447)
    at org.opennms.install.Installer.install(Installer.java:254)
    at org.opennms.install.Installer.main(Installer.java:989)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized role option "createuser"
  Position: 54
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:313)
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.createUser(Migrator.java:337)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Looks like I posted a similar question, hope we can get some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323583/opennms-win-server-installation-issues

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested: the postgres database has changed the `CREATE USER` command. The argument `CREATEUSER` is no longer valid and should be changed to `CREATEROLE`. This should be done in the `create.sql` file where it tries to create the user.

I had a similar case for OpenCMS in `opencms\setup\database\postgresql\create_db.sql` where I changed:

```
#
# replacer = "${database}"
############################

# Create the user;

CREATE USER ${user}
  PASSWORD '${password}'
  CREATEDB CREATEUSER;

#create the database

CREATE DATABASE ${database}
  WITH ENCODING='UNICODE' OWNER=${user};

#commit all (if connection is not autocommit)
commit;
```

for

```
#
# replacer = "${database}"
############################

# Create the user;

CREATE USER ${user}
  PASSWORD '${password}'
  CREATEDB CREATEROLE;

#create the database

CREATE DATABASE ${database}
  WITH ENCODING='UNICODE' OWNER=${user};

#commit all (if connection is not autocommit)
commit;
```

This was after unzipping the war. I rezipped it and then it worked.