# OpenNMS Win Server installation issues

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2012, opennms

I am attempting to install this on my HTPC running server 2012 and have followed the wiki installation guide but when I get to putting port range to search I get these errors. This is the guide: https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-install/guide-install.html#gi-install-opennms-windows

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>SET OPENNMS_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>SET DBNAME=opennms

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>SET DBURL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>SET ETCDIR=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/etc

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>SET SERVLETDIR=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/webapps/opennms

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\standalone-opennms-installer-18.0.2-1\opennms-installer>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -Xmx512m "-Dopennms.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS" "-Dinstall.dir=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS" "-Dinstall.database.name=opennms" "-Dinstall.database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" "-Dinstall.etc.dir=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/etc" "-Dinstall.servlet.dir=C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/webapps/opennms" -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar" org.opennms.bootstrap.InstallerBootstrap -dis -l "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib"
==============================================================================
OpenNMS Installer
==============================================================================

Configures PostgreSQL tables, users, and other miscellaneous settings.

DEBUG: Looks like we're on Windows...  Validating.
WARNING: Unable to retrieve the value for SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CSDVersion
DEBUG: Windows NT Version 6.2, Build 9200 (Service Pack 0)
DEBUG: Platform is IPv6 ready: true
- searching for jicmp.dll:
  - trying to load C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\FileBot\\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Go\bin\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jicmp.dll: NO
  - trying to load .\jicmp.dll: NO
- Failed to load the optional jicmp library.
  - This error is not fatal, since jicmp is only required for optional features.
  - For more information, see http://www.opennms.org/index.php/jicmp
- searching for jicmp6.dll:
  - trying to load C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\FileBot\\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Go\bin\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jicmp6.dll: NO
  - trying to load .\jicmp6.dll: NO
- Failed to load the optional jicmp6 library.
  - This error is not fatal, since jicmp6 is only required for optional features.
  - For more information, see http://www.opennms.org/index.php/jicmp6
- searching for jrrd.dll:
  - trying to load C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\FileBot\\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Go\bin\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jrrd.dll: NO
  - trying to load .\jrrd.dll: NO
- Failed to load the optional jrrd library.
  - This error is not fatal, since jrrd is only required for optional features.
  - For more information, see http://www.opennms.org/index.php/jrrd
- searching for jrrd2.dll:
  - trying to load C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\system32\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\FileBot\\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Go\bin\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load C:\Program Files\nodejs\jrrd2.dll: NO
  - trying to load .\jrrd2.dll: NO
- Failed to load the optional jrrd2 library.
  - This error is not fatal, since jrrd2 is only required for optional features.
  - For more information, see http://www.opennms.org/index.php/jrrd2
- using SQL directory... C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNMS\etc
- using create.sql... C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNMS\etc\create.sql
* using 'postgres' as the PostgreSQL user for OpenNMS
* using 'opennms' as the PostgreSQL database name for OpenNMS
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.opennms.bootstrap.Bootstrap$4.run(Bootstrap.java:460)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opennms.core.schema.MigrationException: an error occurred creating the OpenNMS user
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.createUser(Migrator.java:339)
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.prepareDatabase(Migrator.java:447)
    at org.opennms.install.Installer.install(Installer.java:254)
    at org.opennms.install.Installer.main(Installer.java:989)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized role option "createuser"
  Position: 54
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:313)
    at org.opennms.core.schema.Migrator.createUser(Migrator.java:337)
    ... 9 more
```

Then when trying the start.bat inside opennms i get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNMS\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java"
    -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError    -D
isThreadContextMapInheritable=true    -Dopennms.home="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ope
nNMS"    -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/lib/endorsed"    -
Djava.io.tmpdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/data/tmp"    -Dcom.sun.managemen
t.jmxremote.port=18980    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false    -Dcom.sun.
management.jmxremote.authenticate=false    -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenNMS/
lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar" start
[DEBUG] System property 'opennms.library.jicmp' set to '/C:/Program%20Files%20(x
86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp.dll.  Attempting to load jicmp library from this location.

[DEBUG] System property 'opennms.library.jicmp' set to '/C:/Program%20Files%20(x
86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp.dll.  Attempting to load jicmp library from this location.

[DEBUG] System property 'opennms.library.jicmp6' set to '/C:/Program%20Files%20(
x86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp6.dll.  Attempting to load jicmp6 library from this locati
on.
[DEBUG] System property 'opennms.library.jicmp6' set to '/C:/Program%20Files%20(
x86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp6.dll.  Attempting to load jicmp6 library from this locati
on.
An error occurred while attempting to start the "OpenNMS:Name=TestLoadLibraries"
 service (class org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Manager).  Shutting down and exiting.
javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't lo
ad library: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp6.dll
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(Default
MBeanServerInterceptor.java:841)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBe
anException(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:852)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultM
BeanServerInterceptor.java:821)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801
)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:278)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Invoker.invokeMethods(Invoker.java:207)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Starter.start(Starter.java:154)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Starter.startDaemon(Starter.java:94)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Controller.start(Controller.java:173)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Controller.main(Controller.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.opennms.bootstrap.Bootstrap$4.run(Bootstrap.java:460)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /C:/Program%20Fil
es%20(x86)/OpenNMS/lib/jicmp6.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at org.opennms.protocols.icmp6.ICMPv6Socket.<init>(ICMPv6Socket.java:99)

        at org.opennms.netmgt.icmp.jni6.Jni6IcmpMessenger.<init>(Jni6IcmpMesseng
er.java:65)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.icmp.jni6.Jni6Pinger$1.call(Jni6Pinger.java:162)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.icmp.jni6.Jni6Pinger$1.call(Jni6Pinger.java:160)
        at org.opennms.core.logging.Logging.withPrefix(Logging.java:43)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.icmp.jni6.Jni6Pinger.initialize6(Jni6Pinger.java:1
60)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Manager.testPinger(Manager.java:262)
        at org.opennms.netmgt.vmmgr.Manager.doTestLoadLibraries(Manager.java:229
)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMB
eanIntrospector.java:112)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMB
eanIntrospector.java:46)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.j
ava:237)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultM
BeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        ... 13 more
```

I installed the postSQL and java jdk as required. Setup the sql per instructions. I've noticed some programs such as nodeJS etc it's trying to use which I actually already had installed. Just would love to get this up and running so I can monitor bandwidth and other resources used remotely.

Comment: That is a raft of errors. But instead of posting a link, you should put them in your question to make it easier for those who can help see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured this out - but I had the same issue installing OpenNMS on Windows 2012/R2.  I ended up figuring out that the latest PostGres DB version is the problem.  If you install PostGres v9.2.19  (http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-9219-installers-win64?ls=Crossover&type=Crossover) the installation will complete, as long as the other prereq's are met.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in Centos, whereas Ubuntu installs went fine.  My problem was JAVA.  I had Java_1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64.  The solution was installing Java_1.8.0-openjdk-***devel***.x86-64.

So just uninstall every version of Java, and make sure you install Java, JDK, Developers edition, then try your install again.